# Issues installing BreezeJS with an MVC5 project

Tags: breeze

Via VS2012, I've created a fresh asp.net MVC5 project. I then added a controller with the Web.Api2 template.

I successfully tested the project, and my API layer works fine. i.e. testing with `\api\values\` in my local browser.

I'm now attempting to add the NuGet package, Breeze.Server.WebApi2 located here:

```
    https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Server.WebApi2/1.5.2
```

However, I still cannot access the Breeze controller using localHost port as `/breeze/rage/Get`

I get an oData error :

```
    <ExceptionMessage>
     Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

System.IO.FileLoadException

My csproj,  section:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Breeze.ContextProvider">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.5.2\lib\Breeze.ContextProvider.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.5.2\lib\Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Breeze.WebApi2">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.5.2\lib\Breeze.WebApi2.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.6.3\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.6.3\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.7\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Spatial, Version=5.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Spatial.5.6.3\lib\net40\System.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.OData">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.OData.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
<Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
<Reference Include="WebActivator">
  <HintPath>..\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3\lib\net40\WebActivator.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and the packages.config file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Breeze.Client" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.WebApi2.EF6" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Q" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Your help is appreciated...

thanks,
Bob

Comment: please include the references section of your .csproj and the contents of your packages.config file.

Comment: It looks like your OData package is just out of date.  Have you tried a update?

Comment: @PWKad - my oData version is ~packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.2.2~ , but it appears Breeze is looking for 5.6.0.0. I can't figure out how to update Breeze to use the newer version of oData.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow - contents provided. thank you.

Comment: @bob and any new users - a Nuget package has dependencies.  If the dependency is on a newer version of a package you need to update it.

Comment: @PWKad - Current updated version --> "Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.3". The error when I attempt to access `/breeze/rage/get` is pointing to Version=5.6.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

try adding an assembly binding redirect in your web.config:

```
<config>
  ...

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      ...

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.3.0" newVersion="5.6.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...

    </assemblyBinding>
  <runtime>
  ...

</config>
```

Comment: I've decided to go with straight Web.Api until I find a permanent solution, Thank you.